# Append a specific type of line in a text file to the line before

Tags: python, file

here's my problem. 
I've got a text file which looks like this:

```
[10:03, 24.1.2020] Fabian Obst: Also morgen bin ich nicht da
[10:40, 24.1.2020] Philipp Winterstein: Also los gehts heut um 9 hab ich gehört 

Morgen bin ich dabei 
[10:43, 24.1.2020] Jan Hofmann: Bin wahrscheinlich heut und morgen net da :o
[10:45, 24.1.2020] Manuel Müller: Bin des Wochenende raus
```

With several thousand lines. Sometimes, as you can see in this example, there are paragraphs in the text which I don't want. So I simply want the line without a date at the start to be appended to the line before.

This is how I thought it would work:

```
def cleanfile(previous_line, current_line):
    print (previous_line)
    print (current_line)

file = open('whatsapp.txt','r', encoding="utf8")
data = file.read()
#words = data.split(" ")

if file:
    current_line = file.readline()
for current_line in file:
    if current_line[0] != '[':
        previous_line = current_line
        current_line = line
        cleanfile(previous_line, current_line)

    line = data.split("\n")
file.close()

#print("Data from 26.12.2017 to 23.5.2020.")
print("The number of lines is", len(current_line))
```

Unfortunately, this outputs the following:
`The number of lines is 0`

I tried several different methods to pull this of but so far nothing worked. 
By the way, it works perfectly fine if I do this:

```
file = open('whatsapp.txt','r', encoding="utf8")
data = file.read()
lines = data.split("\n")
print("The number of lines is", len(lines))
```

This outputs `The number of lines is 4020`. But it counts the lines without a date at the start as well, which is what I don't want. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You tried several methods and that must be why there are a couple of redundant lines lingering ... When the file is first opened, you *read* it. Then you do a single `readline` (that is to discard the first line? I assume it's what you want) and *then* a series of single-line reads. But the very first `read` already consumed the entire file.

Answer (score 0):

I found part if out for myself:

```
lines = []
with open('whatsapp.txt','r', encoding="utf8") as file:
    for line in file:
        if line[0] == '[':
            lines.append(line)
```

If anyone else got a problem like this, I found [this link](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001721.htm) very helpful!

But this doesn't solve the problem that I want to append lines which don't start with `[` to the line before. How would I do that?